# How to retrieve two different filetypes inside a Sharepoint folder (jpg thumb trigger - linked to pdf) using Rest API

Tags: rest, fancybox-3, sharepoint-2019

I'm encountering an issue retrieving 2 different file types, `.jpg` and `.pdf`, filed in the same SharePoint folder.

What I'm trying to achieve is retrieve the `.jpg` thumbnail of the publication cover and place them horizontally on the site page; each `.jpg` is wrapped with an anchor tag linked to a `.pdf` file of the publication. This `.pdf` publication with appear in a fancybox popup when the thumbnail is selected.

I'm able to make this happen, with only the `.jpg` files only in the folder, using the `.jpg` file for both the thumbnail and linked file that popup in fancybox. But I need the `.pdf` to be the link file.

Everything I have tried to retrieve the two different file types and place them as mentioned fail. Below is my current script which doesn't display the thumbnail (show a broken link to the `.jpg`). But when I select the broken image link icon, the pdf publication with launch in fancybox. Any ideas anyone can offer to get me on a good path would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getLoggedInUser, "sp.js");
        
getFilesFromFolder("/sites/Creative/Shared%20Documents/Recognition/Quarterly").done(function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item) {
        
    
    $("#container").append('<div class="alignImage blogBox moreBox"><a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" href="https://publication/issues/Pub-"' + i + '".pdf"' + '"href= "javascript:;"> <img src="https://publication/issues/Pub_thumb-"' + i + '".jpg"' + '" id="image"'  + i + '"></a><div class="pub blogBox moreBox"><span id="issue"' + i + '"> DCSA Gatekeeper, ISSUE "'  +  i + '"</span><br>Select icon to read issue.</a></div></div>');
            
        });
    });
```